# "No such module 'FBSDKCoreKit'" on ViewController.swift, How can I fix it?

Tags: swift, xcode, facebook, authentication

I got "No such module 'FBSDKCoreKit'" on ViewController.swift, How can I fix it?

I am now trying to implement a Facebook Login function based on the youtube video that is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6uZ0o6xDA4

However, on the ViewController.swift, I got an error "No such module 'FBSDKCoreKit'". After pod install, there is no error on other .swift files. Only ViewController.swift shows this.

I tried to do "pod install" again because I heard that would work but did not.
Please tell me the way if you are able to.

↓ViewController.swift

```html
// Swift
//
// Add this to the header of your file, e.g. in ViewController.swift

import FBSDKCoreKit

// Add this to the body
class ViewController: UIViewController, LoginButtonDeleate {
    
    


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if let token = AccessToken.current,
            !token.isExpired {
            let token = token.tokenString
            
            let request = FBLoginkit.GraphRequest(graphPath: "me",
                                                  parameters: ["fields": "email name"],
                                                  tokenString,
                                                  version: nil,
                                                  httpMethod: .get)
            request.start(completionHandler: { connection, result, error in
                print("\(result)")
            })
        }
        else{
            let loginButton = FBLoginButton()
            loginButton.center = view.center
            loginButton.delegate = self

            // Swift
            //
            // Extend the code sample from 6a. Add Facebook Login to Your Code
            // Add to your viewDidLoad method:
            loginButton.permissions = ["public_profile", "email"]
            view.addSubview(loginButton)
        }
        
    }
    
    func loginbutton (_ loginbutton: FBLoginbutton, didCompleteWith result: LoginManagementLoginResult?, error : Error){
        let token = result?.token?.tokenString
        
        let request = FBLoginkit.GraphRequest(graphPath: "me",
                                              parameters: ["fields": "email name"],
                                              tokenString: token,
                                              version: nil,
                                              httpMethod: .get)
        request.start(completionHandler: { connection, result, error in
            print("\(result)")
        })
        
    }
    
    func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginBUtton: FBLoginButton) {
    }
}
```

Comment: did you install  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'??

Comment: Did you opened the xcworkspace and not the xcodeproj after installing it with CocoaPods ? Does it appear in the pods frameworks?

Comment: No, it did at first and seems like similor, I will try that way. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import FBSDKLoginKit instead of FBSDKCoreKit

Comment: Same result. No such module 'FBSDKLoginKit'